# "This / that much, this / that high, this / that thick" in spoken English

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Conversation between two friends:

> A:  Hey, John, how tall is your son?
>
> B: well, he has become **this high.**(*showing with his hand)*

Two cute little kids are talking about their tv:

> A: Our new TV is **this big.** *(showing with two hands)*
>
> B: Our TV is **that big.** (*pointing his finger at a cupboard)*

Are the set of words natural in sopken English?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The **bold** part of all of your examples is correct and idiomatic.

Note that we only use the word **become** when describing a change of state or degree, for example:

> Your son will soon **become a man** - *a change of state, from boy to man*
>   Cars have become **become more streamlined** over the past 30 years - *a comparison between how things were,and how they are now*

Describing your son's height is not a change- you are simply saying how tall he is now- so you just say

> well, he **is** this high. (showing with his hand)